# DFT matlab problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis

We have signal $\sin(2\pi v_1 t)+\sin(2\pi v_2 t)$ and we know $ν_1\in{700,780,860,940}$ and $ν_2\in{1200,1340,1480}$. Also we have vector [here](http://math.aalto.fi/opetus/ms-c1420/har14/stackfftA9.m): $$h(k)=\sin(2π ν_1 k Δt)+\sin(2π ν_2 k Δt)$$
where $\Delta t=1/8000$ and $k=1,\dots ,1000$. What are $ν_1$ and $ν_2$? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to Matlab right now, but something like this should work:

```
N = length(h);
f = 8000 * (-0.5 : 1/N : 0.5-1/N);
H = fftshift( fft( h ) );
plot( f, abs(H) );
```

Look for the peaks in the spectrum.

Comment: Thanks! I gotta check myself (don't have matlab on my home computer).

Comment: Damnit. Tried to install matlab to my computer, but I have too old distro ..

Comment: How do I add those rows of data of the vector $h$ to that matlab command?

Comment: $ν_1 \in 700,780,860,940$ and $ν_2\in 1200,1340,1480$. The answer is one of those.(obv) It's so frustrating without matlab. I have tried with wolfram with no success.

Comment: @ELEC You can either copy-and-paste the contents of the file to the workspace, or you can execute the file as a script. I get the following [plot](http://imgur.com/pajkKwQ). It looks like the frequencies are 780 and 1340.

Comment: Thanks @AnonSubmitter85. I got the same result!